# Using multiple "WHEN MATCHED" for update and an insert with merge in db2

Tags: sql, merge, db2

Within a PHP script I'm running a working merge but I need to add date conditionals to it, and my updates cause it to no longer work.

The logic I'm looking for is this:

1. If there's a match AND the expire_date is before today, do an insert
2. If there's a match AND the expire_date is after today, do an update
3. If no match, just insert

The matching has been working but I basically want to disregard matches that are expired. What am I doing wrong here?

This is running in db2 for iseries

```
                    MERGE INTO products AS P
                    USING ( VALUES (
                        CAST(:CUSTOMER AS INT),
                        CAST(:SLSCODE AS INT),
                        CAST(:DTL1 AS INT),
                        CAST(:DTL2 AS INT),
                        CAST(:DTL3 AS INT),
                        CAST(:COUNT AS INT),
                        CAST(:LAST_DATE AS DATE),
                        CAST(:FLAG AS SMALLINT),
                        CAST(:ORDER AS INT),
                        CAST(:PIECES AS VARCHAR(45))
                        )
                    )
                AS S(CUSTOMER,REGION,DTL1,DTL2,DTL3,COUNT,LAST_DATE,FLAG,ORDER,PIECES)
                ON s.CUSTOMER = p.CUSTOMER and s.REGION = p.REGION and s.DTL1 = p.DTL1 and s.DTL2 = p.DTL2 and s.DTL3 = p.DTL3 and s.COUNT = p.COUNT and s.LAST_DATE = p.LAST_DATE and s.FLAG = p.FLAG and s.ORDER = p.ORDER AND s.PIECES = p.PIECES


                WHEN MATCHED AND p.expire_date > current_date
                    THEN UPDATE SET  last_date = s.last_date, order = s.order, pieces = s.pieces, expire_date = s.expire_date

                WHEN MATCHED AND p.expire_date < current_date
                    THEN INSERT VALUES (s.customer,s.region, s.dtl1, s.dtl2, s.dtl3, s.count, s.last_date, s.flag, s.order, s.pieces, s.expire_date)

                WHEN NOT MATCHED
                    THEN INSERT VALUES (s.customer,s.region, s.dtl1, s.dtl2, s.dtl3, s.count, s.last_date, s.flag, s.order, s.pieces, s.expire_date)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's [cross-posted on dba.se and has an answer there](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228007/using-a-db2-merge-with-conditionals-for-matches).

Comment: It would be a pain to google and find no answer on a closed post.